# Tableview not reloading after data change : IOS 5

Tags: tableview, reloaddata

I need help in following scenario.

I am building an app that displays tableview. If the user tap an entry it goes to the detailed screen. In the detail screen, I have a button to delete this entry. It deletes the entry from the data source and dismiss the modal.

But after dismissing the modal, table view data is not refreshing.

If I go back to parent view controller and then again come back to child screen, it refreshes the count.

I read few similar posts and found the following solution.

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

Or

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

In    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated of child screen.
But its not refreshing the table view.

Please help.

Comment: Got the answer from .....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437423/tableview-reloaddata-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the full implementation would be:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Do stuff like reload the tableview data...
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

If it's not working you have a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: It's important to call 'super' in all view delegation methods.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tableview is in the parent viewcontroller, I suggest that placing reloadData: method at viewWillAppear: of the parent.

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I'm sure that the method will be called when the detailed viewcontroller dismissed.